# How do I loop through a multidimensional array to retrieve keys where the value is one?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, laravel-5

Here is my array: `[["STR_License_Driver",1],["STR_License_Truck",0],["STR_License_Pilot",1],["STR_License_Firearm",0],["STR_License_Rifle",0]]`

My goal is to make an array or string (unsure of best method) called `results` where the value of the licenses is 1.

For example: The results should be something like: `STR_Licenses_Driver, STR_Licenses_Pilot`.

I am currently using PHP Version 7, and Laravel Version 5.5

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON Decode the $this->license and do the loop.

**Whole code:**

```
$licenses  = $this->licenses;//This is your posted array string

$result = json_decode($licenses);
$licenses_with_1 = array();
foreach($result as $i){
   foreach($i as $key => $value){
       if($value == 1){
            $licenses_with_1[] = $i[0];
       }
   }
}
print_r($licenses_with_1);
```

**Result:**

```
Array ( [0] => STR_License_Driver [1] => STR_License_Pilot )
```

Comment: ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: I understand what you mean with the associative array part now. Thank you for editing your answer to clarify it.

Comment: I am working on testing it by setting the array in the script to check if it's something on larvel's end. But with your method, how would I add the keys to an array `results`?

Comment: Now how would I make `echo $i[0] . "<br />";` and array or string as `results`?

Comment: I used echo $i[0] . "<br />"; for the sake of demo. Do you want it store in array?

Comment: I understand the echo part, and it does work. I would just like it in an array so that I can use it later.

Comment: ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Undefined variable: licenses_with_1

Comment: See my updated answer i forgot to add $licenses_with_1 = array();

Comment: Just use substr. substr("STR_Licenses_Pilot", 4);

Answer (score 1):

```
$licenses = [["STR_License_Driver",1],["STR_License_Truck",0],["STR_License_Pilot",1],["STR_License_Firearm",0],["STR_License_Rifle",0]];
```

Map over filtered array having second item equal to 1 to get the license names.

```
$filterVal = 1;
$licenseNames = array_map(
                  function ($item) { return $item[0]; }, 
                  array_filter(
                    $licenses, 
                    function ($item) use ($filterVal) { return $item[1] === $filterVal; }
                  )
                );
```

Then **implode** array of license names to join by glue string.

```
echo implode($licenseNames, ', ');
```

Comment: Is there an extra part to this, because it I believe it's returned empty.

Comment: No extra part. Check this Repl to confirm if any step was missed. https://repl.it/Nva4/0

Comment: Whenever I just pull the field out of the database (besides the numbers are different due to my example), this is what is outputted: [["STR_License_Driver",0],["STR_License_Truck",0],["STR_License_Pilot",0],["STR_License_Firearm",0],["STR_License_Rifle",0]] | However, I get an error saying it's not an array when using array_filter.

Comment: I have factored out the filter value so that you can pre-assign it a value. `implode` returns a string so I assume you need to assign its return value to a variable and pass that to your template.

Comment: You may need to convert your db results to an array. If you'll like to confirm the data type for your db results you can use PHP `gettype` function. Also there's the `toArray` method callable on query instances to convert results to array.

Answer (score 1):

I remember Python on your data structure.

Try my solution:
https://3v4l.org/nrfqZ